# UITableView with a UISearchBar as the header view causes crashes

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uipopovercontroller, ios7

I have a popover with a `UITableViewController` as the content view controller. The table view has a `UISearchBar` as its header view.

Everything is ok on iOS 6, but on iOS 7 the app crashes when closing the popover giving this error:

```
*** -[UIView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x118a9bf0
```

[image: Call stack]

Any idea about the possible cause for this crash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I fixed it. I set the table's header view to `nil` when the view controller is being deallocated:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
}
```

Though, this doesn't explain the real reason for the crash.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up calling `[searchBar removeFromSuperview]` in dealloc - same fix.

Comment: For a while you'd need to study the UIKit source code. I guess otherwise some async animation is fired.